# DXT1 compressed textures are not supported when publishing to iPhone

Tags: unity-game-engine, compression, textures

plaise help me 
this error in unity 2019.3.0a5 any solution unity developper 
Debug log :

> DXT1 compressed textures are not supported when publishing to iPhone 
>   Resources/unity_builtin_extra  Included from scene:  0 Unity
>   0x000000010f08213f _Z13GetStacktracei + 95  1 Unity 0x0000000111849a54
>   _Z17DebugStringToFileRK21DebugStringToFileData + 356  2 Unity 0x000000010e61d572
>   _Z23VerifyFeatureDeploymentP6Object19BuildTargetPlatform + 2082  3 Unity 0x000000010e613209
>   _Z16VerifyDeploymentP6Object19BuildTargetPlatform + 1273  4 Unity 0x000000010ef2fdcc
>   _ZN17PersistentManager9WriteFileERKN4core12basic_stringIcNS0_20StringStorageDefaultIcEEEEiPK9WriteDataiRK15GlobalBuildDataPF23VerifyWriteObjectResultP6Object19BuildTargetPlatformE20BuildTargetSelection24TransferInstructionFlagsR16WriteInformationPK18InstanceIDResolverNS_9LockFlagsE
>   + 3084  5 Unity 0x000000010ef2f093 _ZN17PersistentManager9WriteFileERKN4core12basic_stringIcNS0_20StringStorageDefaultIcEEEEiPK9WriteDataiRK15GlobalBuildDataPF23VerifyWriteObjectResultP6Object19BuildTargetPlatformE20BuildTargetSelection24TransferInstructionFlagsPK18InstanceIDResolverNS_9LockFlagsE
>   + 179  6 Unity 0x000000010e61235b _Z20WriteSharedAssetFileiRKN4core12basic_stringIcNS_20StringStorageDefaultIcEEEERKNSt3__13mapIi10BuildAssetNS6_4lessIiEENS6_9allocatorINS6_4pairIKiS8_EEEEEERK19BuildUsageTagGlobal20BuildTargetSelectionPFviR31LocalSerializedObjectIdentifierPvE24TransferInstructionFlagsRNS6_3setI12ResourceFileNS9_ISU_EENSB_ISU_EEEER10vector_mapIi26SerializedObjectIdentifierSA_NSB_INSC_IiS10_EEEEE
>   + 1099  7 Unity 0x000000010e613597 _Z23CompileSharedAssetsFileiRKN4core12basic_stringIcNS_20StringStorageDefaultIcEEEES5_RKNSt3__13mapIi10BuildAssetNS6_4lessIiEENS6_9allocatorINS6_4pairIKiS8_EEEEEERK19BuildUsageTagGlobalRK20BuildTargetSelection24TransferInstructionFlagsRNS6_3setI12ResourceFileNS9_ISR_EENSB_ISR_EEEER10vector_mapIi26SerializedObjectIdentifierSA_NSB_INSC_IiSX_EEEEERN14BuildReporting11BuildReportE
>   + 135  8 Unity 0x000000010e62b966 _ZL15BuildPlayerData24BuildTargetPlatformGroup19BuildTargetPlatform18BuildPlayerOptionsRK16BuildCompressionNSt3__16vectorIN4core12basic_stringIcNS7_20StringStorageDefaultIcEEEENS5_9allocatorISB_EEEEP20AssetBundleBuildDataRNS6_I17EditorSceneBackup13stl_allocatorISH_L18MemLabelIdentifier116ELi16EEEE18ScriptingObjectPtr8Vector2fRN14BuildReporting11BuildReportERKSB_PNSP_20BuiltAssetBundleInfoEST_
>   + 12038  9 Unity 0x000000010e600753 _Z13DoBuildPlayerRK16BuildPlayerSetupRNSt3__16vectorI17EditorSceneBackup13stl_allocatorIS4_L18MemLabelIdentifier116ELi16EEEEN4core12basic_stringIcNSA_20StringStorageDefaultIcEEEENS3_ISE_NS2_9allocatorISE_EEEEbRN14BuildReporting11BuildReportEPNSI_20BuiltAssetBundleInfoERKSE_
>   + 3587  10 Unity 0x000000010e605196 _Z11BuildPlayerRK16BuildPlayerSetupRN14BuildReporting11BuildReportE + 4102  11 Unity 0x000000010f74fa94
>   _Z47BuildPipeline_CUSTOM_BuildPlayerInternalNoCheckP36ScriptingBackendNativeArrayPtrOpaqueP37ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaqueS2_24BuildTargetPlatformGroup19BuildTargetPlatform18BuildPlayerOptionsh
>   + 1204  12 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
>   (string[],string,string,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,bool)
>   13 (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:170]
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer
>   (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)  14 (Mono JIT Code)
>   [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96]
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods
>   (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)  15 (Mono JIT Code)
>   [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:913]
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons
>   (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, it's a bug in Unity, that happens sometimes, many people reported it.

One of the fixes that worked for some people is: "Right click in Project Assets folder and Reimport All."

Here is this issue reported on Unity site: [Link to Issue](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-build-fails-with-an-error-dxt1-compressed-textures-are-not-supported-when-publishing-to-iphone). There are some other suggestions how to fix it in the comments, if fix above wouldn't work for you.

Answer (score 3):

This message means that a texture you're using is set to use DXT1 compression, in your case in scene 0.
Resources/unity_builtin_extra are built-in textures and there is e.g. Default-Checker-Gray that has that compression set (and you can't change it). So you can't have that attached to any material you're using or also not using (can't have it in any Resources folder).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. But. Solved it by removing my Resources  folder from Assets folder. Just moved all subfolders to Assets and then build was successful!

Answer (score 0):

Find the material usind Default-Checker-Gray and change its albedo to Default-Checker or smth else.
This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use default icon or splash image.
Replace them, in build setting Unity

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't resolved this issue yet then try these solutions.

1- First change all textures from DXT1 to any other compression that is supported for Iphone. Am using RGBA Compressed ASTC.

2- Check all your materials, there will be any material which is using unity built in texture named "Default-Checker-Gray". Just delete this texture from that material and it will resolve your issue. image is also attached below for quick reference.

[Default Checker Gray Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p93ab.png)

Option 2 resolved my issue and now am able to build Xcode project.